# Style resizable divs to always take up the entire page

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to get 4 div elements with borders to take up the entire page, and have them all resizable. When you resize one,the rest should conform with the one you're actively resizing, so that there are never any empty spaces. The borders should always be visible on all sides.

I've uploaded what I've got right now to https://jsfiddle.net/f8yqu43q/

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. I'd also settle for only being able to resize the sides or bottom, one at a time. Similar to how JSFiddle handles it actually. Below I've posted the code I'm working with locally, since stack overflow forces me to post code when sharing a JSFiddle link

```
<html>
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='app.js'></script>
<script
  src='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js'
  integrity='sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30='
  crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
  href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='stylesheet.css'>
  <body>

    <div id='NW'></div>
    <div id='SW'></div>
    <div id='SE'></div>
    <div id='NE'></div>
      <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#NW" ).resizable({
        alsoResize: '#SW,#SE,#NE'
    });
  } );
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS

```
html, body { height:100%; margin:0; padding:0 }
div { position:fixed; width:50%; height:50% }
#NW { top:0;   left:0;   border-style:solid;border-width:6px;border-color:gray;  }
#NE { top:0;   left:50%; border-style:solid;border-width:6px;border-color:gray;    }
#SW { top:50%; left:0;   border-style:solid;border-width:6px;border-color:gray;   }
#SE { top:50%; left:50%; border-style:solid;border-width:6px;border-color:gray;     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `box-sizing: border-box;` to all 4 blocks, without it your width does not count border so each block is 50% + 12px (border both side), that why you border shift out:

> ## CSS3 Box Sizing
>
> The CSS3 box-sizing property allows us to include the padding and border in an element's total width and height.
>
> Without the CSS3 box-sizing Property
>   By default, the width and height of an element is calculated like this:
>
> #### width + padding + border = actual width of an element
>
> #### height + padding + border = actual height of an element
>
> This means: When you set the width/height of an element, the element often appear bigger than you have set (because the element's border and padding are added to the element's specified width/height).
>
> REF: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var nw = $("#NW"),
    sw = $("#SW"),
    se = $("#SE"),
    ne = $("#NE"),
    body = $('body');
  var swse = $("#SW, #SE"),
    nwne = $("#NW, #NE");

  $("#NW").resize(function() {
    resizeNW();
  });

  function resizeNW() {
    ne.width(parseInt(body.width() - nw.width() - 12));
    ne.height(parseInt(nw.height() - 12));
    ne.css('left', parseInt(nw.width()));
    swse.height(parseInt(body.height() - nw.height() - 12));
    swse.css('top', parseInt(nw.height()));
    sw.width(parseInt(nw.width() - 12));
    se.width(parseInt(body.width() - nw.width() - 12));
    se.css('left', parseInt(nw.width()));
  }

  $("#NW").resizable({});
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%
}

#NW,
#SW,
#SE,
#NE {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 6px;
  border-color: gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#NW {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#NE {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
}

#SW {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}

#SE {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js' integrity='sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

<body>

  <div id='NW'>nw</div>
  <div id='SW'>sw</div>
  <div id='SE'>se</div>
  <div id='NE'>ne</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that seems to give me the same result I had before

Comment: @EthanHartman what you mean? Do you want same border width in the center?

Comment: @EthanHartman try hard reload your browser, might be css style sheet not updated

Comment: When I resize one div, it should push the others back, making them smaller. Instead they just overlap. Currently when you drag to the right and down, it creates the appearance of 9 boxes.

Comment: Well they don't overlap there, so it's some progress! But when you drag into another div, that div should get smaller. and when you drag away, not only the active one should get smaller, the ones around it should get larger and take up the missing space.

Comment: @EthanHartman ok, check the updated one, that should let you start doing it

Comment: Wow looks great! Needs some work on the responsiveness but I believe I can take it from here. Thank you very much!